# ESRI color gradient map theme in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Heat maps in Power BI are based on distance. What I would like is a color gradient (i.e. a smooth color transition from one color to the other) between points of different color.

Here are some examples of wind potential energy and biodiversity possibly made is similar ways:

[image]
[image]

The algorithm that calculates the gradient is not so important, only the visualization.

Any thoughts about whether this is possible?

Comment: If the default map visualisations are unable to do that, another option is to try finding something in the [visuals gallery](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=power-bi-visuals&page=1). Or, depending on how much work you can afford to do for this you could [create your own custom visual](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-sampleBarChart).